# Why does jQuery resize detection not work on my DOM element?

Tags: jquery, dom, resize

I need to detect when an element resizes for the purposes of responsive content. The examples I see all detect if the window has resized, but I can't find how to detect if a DOM element resizes. For instance, the following only counts window resizes:

HTML:

```
<div id="resizer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac accumsan elit, sit amet ultrices massa. Pellentesque iaculis nulla ut fringilla pellentesque. Duis ut suscipit libero. Sed et mauris nisl.</div>
<output id="output1">Div not yet resized.</output>
<output id="output2">Window not yet resized.</output>
```

JS:

```
var divResizes = 0;
$("#resizer").resize(function(){
    $('#output1').html("Div resized " + ++divResizes + " times.");
});
var windowResizes = 0;
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#output2').html("Window resized " + ++windowResizes + " times.");
});
```

Sample output after resizing the window:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac
>   accumsan elit, sit amet ultrices massa. Pellentesque iaculis nulla ut
>   fringilla pellentesque. Duis ut suscipit libero. Sed et mauris nisl.
>   Div not yet resized. Window resized 23 times.

SSCCE: http://jsfiddle.net/3K2YY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

"The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes:"

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

The thing is that the jQuery UI function resizable does trigger the browser event 'resize'.
So you can see in the updated jsFiddle, that changing the size of the "resizer" div results in counts for both, but the delayed change in size, does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/3K2YY/2/

```
t = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#resizer").width("50%");

}, 2000);
```

You should find additional events/listeners to detect this change. I'm not realy sure if that is possible.
You could just use the window resize event to (re)check the dimensions of other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Only `window` has in the official spec a `onresize` event. Use a polyfill from

https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

to make it work.

This library has a class `ResizeSensor` which you can use.

```
var divResizes = 0;
new ResizeSensor($("#resizer"), function(){
    $('#output1').html("Div resized " + ++divResizes + " times.");
});
```

Comment: +1 for a working answer, but I can't justify using an entire library for one function.

Comment: Entire library? Just download this one class file and you're good to go.

Comment: Alright, I tried that at http://jsfiddle.net/Supuhstar/3K2YY/16/ but I'm concerned about the several elements it adds, and the fact that it forces the target element to be `position:relative`. It's a reliable solution, but I wouldn't use it in production since I don't know how it'd affect a complex website.